# Why do fonts look messed up in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: fonts, adobe-acrobat

When I open a PDF in a non-Acrobat PDF viewer, they look fine, but when I open one in Acrobat, the fonts look absolutely terrible. They look very low resolution and I'm not sure how to increase them.

I've tried PDFs from internet, exporting from Word, and making LaTeX documents.

How can I correct this problem?

Comment: If you're wondering if this question applies to you and you don't have a non-Acrobat viewer installed, the PDF should look fine when you print it as well.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Did you make any changes in Adobe Reader? See the below default settings for Page display (go to Edit | Preferences):

[image]

To increase the resolution increase the pixels/inch from the Resolution section

Comment: It was actually the "Smooth Text" option that needed fixing. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect. I've been putting up with pixelly fonts for months because I thought it was a Windows 8 defect. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file on someone else's computer and see if they have the same issue.  If not, the first thing I would try is to uninstall adobe acrobat and then install the latest version.  You could also try installing older versions of Adobe reader here: http://www.oldapps.com/adobe_reader.php