# Adobe Reader renders Times fonts fuzzy

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, pdf-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do fonts look messed up in Adobe Acrobat?](https://superuser.com/questions/156525/why-do-fonts-look-messed-up-in-adobe-acrobat)

The first row are times fonts, rendered by PDF XChange Viewer( or Sumatra, Evince, their rendering are almost the same) and Adobe Reader. The second row are [STIX font](http://www.stixfonts.org).

It can be seen that PDF XChange Viewer (and Sumatra, Evince, ...) renders Times and STIX almost the same way, while in Adobe Reader, Times are greyer and thinner, especially the letter "s".

So is there a way to make Adobe Reader display Times font concretely black?

My laptop configuration: Windows 7, Adobe Reader 10.1 with Cooltype turned on, NVidia driver 275.50.

And when the graphics driver is removed, Adobe Reader will render correctly.

[image: Times Other]  [image: Times Adobe]

[image: STIX Other]  [image: STIX Adobe]

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that cleartype is misconfigured and one software is aware of it (more likely adobe),  and the other isn't - you can adjust this in Windows Control Panel under Appearance and Personalization

EDIT: you might want to take a look at this. My guess now is, you can tweak [cooltype](http://books.google.com/books?id=TuGQpeIxrqQC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=adjusting%20cooltype&source=bl&ots=g77rf_YdqV&sig=jJ_J6mmdMhFNuvgrASVIBsL6KkE&hl=en&ei=u88fTtHNOpDSrQeKwrCiAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).. about the same way. Its for an older version so it might be outdated. The newer versions have only 3 options apparently

Comment: Adobe Reader uses its own subpixel rendering technology---cooltype.

Comment: The other two option for Cooltype don't help.