# Why do fonts appear different (thinner) in adobe acrobat compared to other pdf viewers?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have seen that this question has been [raised in the past](https://superuser.com/questions/156525/why-do-fonts-look-messed-up-in-adobe-acrobat) and the OP was able to resolve it by turning on smooth text, but my settings are default yet there compared to the foxit and web viewer the pdf font texts in Adobe Acrobat are thinner, which is quite a strain on eyes. I have also tried changing the custom resolution but that also as such doesn't have any effect.

View in Foxit

[image: View in Foxit]

View in Adobe Acrobat

[image: View in Adobe Acrobat]

Acrobat Settings

[image: Acrobat Settings]

Comment: Adobe Acrobat's defaults may not be Foxit's defaults. The "for LCD screens" probably means ClearType which usually looks smoother. It will also depend on your system's ClearType calibration.

Comment: Try in your above Acrobat Settings to uncheck *Use local fonts*.

Comment: @harrymc, Yes I did try that but still the same.

Comment: Your PDF doesn't contain the fonts embedded, so the choice of fonts is in the hands of the viewer and its defaults and what's available in your system. The criteria for this choice might be different.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, but is there any way to mimic it in the same way as Foxit? Cause I prefer adobe acrobat since it has better highlight and comment features, but it's really difficult to read with this Serif fonts that appear thin.